# Update Docker image and container from Jenkins

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins, docker

I am quite new to Jenkins and Docker so I am stuck with trying to make them work together. What I want is to do next steps:

1. Build my project war-file on Jenkins (Done)
2. Update Docker image and container. In my case I want to stop running container (Tomcat on it), change war-file to the newest and then run it again.

I've already deploy my application on Docker, but this app is not updated by Jenkins.

I found some plugins, like [docker-build-step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+build+step+plugin) or [docker-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin), however there are not enough information and tutorials about it and I find it really annoying spending hours and making random suggestions.

I would appetiate any useful tutorial as more spesific as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't need any of these plugins. You can implement it using command api of docker.

1. You need to install docker on the jenkins host machine.
2. Then in your Jenkins build config mvn plugin(or execute shell) to build target:

   clean package assembly:assembly -Dmaven.test.skip=true
3. execute shell something like:

`docker build --net=host -t reg.docker.xxx.com/xxx/xxx:latest ./
    docker login --username=xxx --password=xxx   reg.docker.xxx.com
    docker push reg.docker.xxx.com/xxx/xxx:latest`

4. execute shell bellow:

`docker -H tcp://swarm.xxx.com:<port> --tlsverify --tlscacert=./ca.pem --tlscert=./cert.pem --tlskey=./key.pem run  -v /home/admin/rc.local:/etc/rc.local:ro reg.docker.xxx.com/xxx/xxx:latest`

------Edit-------

use docker `upgrade` if updating existing containers.